# pentaho add list to a SQL where in clause

Tags: sql, where-clause, pentaho

I have a Penthao transformation in which the output column from a sql query from a database needs to be inserted as a list in a query on another database in the where in ([list]) clause. This in step would be

1. run query on db1
2. turn the column into a list pass this list inside
3. pass this list inside the where clause of the second query

I understand this may not be a straightforward question but if somebody understand where I am struggling, at least pointing me to the right direction may be very useful.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a `Stream lookup` you can do it like this. Create a job that contains two transformation steps. Add a parameter to the job (I'm calling mine "list").

[image: Job with Parameters]

In your first transform, read your list of values from the DB. I just hard-coded mine with a `Data grid`. Construct the list of values with a `Group by` step.

[image: Group by]

Note that the last step is a `Set Variables` step. Select your variable name as the output and be sure to select "Valid in the parent job" as variable scope type.

**Edit:**

[image: Set variables config]

Now you can use this variable in a `Table input` step in the next transform. Note that "Replace variables in script?" is checked.

[image: Table input config]

This is avoiding scripting steps. You can achieve the same results with a `Modified Javascript value` step, and if this solution doesn't meet your needs, you may have to pursue that approach.

Comment: @blue-moon: You may also use Transformation Executor step inside GetValueList.ktr to call UseValueList.ktr. This step has an option to pass field value from one transformation into another transformation as a variable.

Comment: Could you show me the set variables step in the first transformation? I am having troubles setting in it up

Comment: Added the config for `Set variables`. Are you sure it's that your having trouble with, and not the `Group by`?